# Can I copy JUint test cases folder from one workspace to another in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

If I o the above thing I am getting JUnit Not found prompt in eclipse.

Comment: You still need to set up the project for JUnit.

Comment: did you add a JUnit jar to your test project?